# How do I find the latest object based on a date that is deeply nested in some combination of arrays and objects?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a particularly challenging data structure (that I don't control) where I need to find the latest object based on a combination of nested arrays and objects, while some of the properties along the way are optional. So far, I've managed to filter away where the optional properties definitely exist, but convincing javascript to pull the dates up so I can compare them to find the latest is proving challenging.

Here's the data structure:

```
const data = {
  "objects": [
    {
      "id": "id1",
      "code": "code1",
      "props": [
        {
          "foos": [
            {
              "itemId": "theItem",
              "fooDate": "2018-03-01T10:00:00.000Z"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": "id2",
      "code": "code2",
      "props": [
        {
          "bar": {
            "itemId": "theItem",
            "barDate": "2018-03-06T22:00:00.000Z"
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": "id3",
      "code": "code3",
      "props": [
        {
          "foos": [
            {
              "itemId": "someOtherItem",
              "fooDate": "2018-01-23T06:00:00.000Z"
            },
            {
              "itemId": "theItem",
              "fooDate": "2018-03-04T18:00:00.000Z"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}

const searchItem = "theItem";

const foosOnly = data.objects.filter(obj => obj.props.find(prop => prop.foos && prop.foos.find(foo => foo.itemId === searchItem)));
```

What I'm trying to find is the object with the most recent `fooDate` for "theItem" so that I can operate on some of the top-level properties of the object like `id` or `code`. In this example, I expect "id3" to be the most recent despite also having "someOtherItem" with an older `fooDate`.

I've managed to remove objects that do not contain a `foo` with filter and find, but I struggle to act on `fooDate` in comparison between the `foos` so I can find the latest `foo`.

Comment: *"I've managed to remove objects that do not contain a foo with filter and find, but I struggle to act on fooDate in comparison between the foos so I can find the latest foo.'* Please show us that.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: I added the filter example. I didn't add it initially because I didn't want to influence the solution too much since I'm assuming there's a way to do this without this line of code.

Answer (score 1):

The format of `fooDate` means you can compare it lexicographically. Looking for `fooDate` just means doing a lot of guards and loops:

```
let latest = null;
let latestDate = null;
for (const item of data.objects) {
    if (Array.isArray(item.props)) {
        for (const prop of item.props) {
            if (prop.foo) {
                for (const {fooDate} of prop.foo) {
                    if (fooDate && (!latestDate || fooDate > latestDate)) {
                        latest = item;
                        latestDate = fooDate;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Live Example:

```js
const data = {
  "objects": [
    {
      "id": "id1",
      "code": "code1",
      "props": [
        {
          "foo": [
            {
              "itemId": "theItem",
              "fooDate": "2018-03-01T10:00:00.000Z"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": "id2",
      "code": "code2",
      "props": [
        {
          "bar": [
            {
              "itemId": "theItem",
              "barDate": "2018-03-06T22:00:00.000Z"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": "id3",
      "code": "code3",
      "props": [
        {
          "foo": [
            {
              "itemId": "someOtherItem",
              "fooDate": "2018-01-23T06:00:00.000Z"
            },
            {
              "itemId": "theItem",
              "fooDate": "2018-03-04T18:00:00.000Z"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
};

let latest = null;
let latestDate = null;
for (const item of data.objects) {
    if (Array.isArray(item.props)) {
        for (const prop of item.props) {
            if (prop.foo) {
                for (const {fooDate} of prop.foo) {
                    if (fooDate && (!latestDate || fooDate > latestDate)) {
                        latest = item;
                        latestDate = fooDate;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

console.log(latest);
```

Comment: Hmm, makes sense. The coding background on this team is functional (most of our stuff is in Scala) so I was definitely trying to take a different approach with filter/find/reduce. But the data structure is pretty annoying to work with so I'm not going to be picky about it. The only thing I think that is missing is verifying that `itemId` is equal to "theItem". If "id3" has the `itemId`s swapped, then "id1" would be the most recent. I can probably handle that though.

Comment: @Ellesedil - You could filter and sort but it would be inefficient. If you're looking for an FP approach, probably just convert those loops into recursive function calls, passing in the "latest" information and returning updated "latest" information.

Comment: Hmm, this actually seems to always take the last object in the array regardless of the dates. :(

Comment: @Ellesedil - Ah, the last object in the sample data was the one with the latest date, so I missed it. Fixed now (the missing bit was `latestDate = fooDate;`).

Answer (score 1):

I started going down the route of navigating the object hierarchy, but there seemed like too many unknowns. So, if you’re only curious about a property called `fooDate`, here’s a solution that loops through the objects, stringify’s each one, and uses regex to get the date:

```
let latest = null;
data.objects.forEach(obj => {
    const json = JSON.stringify(obj);
    const regex = new RegExp(/^.+"fooDate":"(.+)".+$/);
    const match = json.match(regex);
    if (match && match.length > 1) {
        const [first, ...results] = match;
        results.forEach(result => {
            const timestamp = new Date(result).valueOf();
            if (!latest || latest.timestamp < timestamp) {
                latest = { obj, timestamp };
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Below code should help you achieve the desired object. If it works, I 'll add comments too.

```js
const data={"objects":[{"id":"id1","code":"code1","props":[{"foos":[{"itemId":"theItem","fooDate":"2018-03-01T10:00:00.000Z"}]}]},{"id":"id2","code":"code2","props":[{"bar":{"itemId":"theItem","barDate":"2018-03-06T22:00:00.000Z"}}]},{"id":"id3","code":"code3","props":[{"foos":[{"itemId":"someOtherItem","fooDate":"2018-01-23T06:00:00.000Z"},{"itemId":"theItem","fooDate":"2018-03-04T18:00:00.000Z"}]}]}]};

const list = data.objects;

const desiredObject = list.sort((itemA, itemB) => {
  let itemAFoo = itemA.props.reduce((list, prop) => {return list.concat(prop.foos || [])}, []).sort((a, b) => a.fooDate - b.fooDate).pop() || {fooDate: 0};
  let itemBFoo = itemA.props.reduce((list, prop) => {return list.concat(prop.foos || [])}, []).sort((a, b) => a.fooDate - b.fooDate).pop() || {fooDate: 0};
  return itemAFoo.fooDate - itemBFoo.fooDate;
}).pop();

desiredItemId = desiredObject.props.reduce((list, prop) => {return list.concat(prop.foos || [])}, []).pop().itemId;

console.log('desiredObject:', desiredObject);
console.log('desiredItemId:', desiredItemId);
```

Comment: Does this just compare all of the dates?

Comment: only foos foodates.

Comment: It only looks at the *first* entry in `props`, though.

Comment: Where would you add filtering on `itemId` in here?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder props always has only 1 item.

Comment: That's not necessarily true. It's definitely an array, and I have no control over the data. My example might have only 1, but the contract I have to implement allows for more than one.

Comment: @Ellesedil. i expected you to find only the outer object. Just `updated` the code to fetch `itemId`

Comment: I do want to find the outer object. However, I need to filter the dates to where `itemId` is "theItem" before sorting them.

Comment: @Ellesedil. I have updated code for all your requirements in comments. If you feel, I can make a jsbin demo for it.

Comment: @GauravSaraswat - No need for jsBin: 
 https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/

Answer (score 0):

Here's some code for what I think would fix your issue. The objective of this method would be to create a new data structure of type

```
{
  id: string;
  itemId: string;
  date: Date;
}
```

after which you can simply filter/sort and search. So let's see how we can create above data.

Something along the lines of

```
const intermediateData = [];

function findItemIdAndDateRecursively(id, object) {
  Object.keys(object).forEach((key) => {
    if(key === 'itemId') {
      let date;
      for(let i in object) {
        if (isUTCString(object[i])) {
          date = object[i];
        }
      }
      intermediateData.push({id: id, itemId: object.itemId, date: date})
    } else if (typeof object[key] === 'object' || typeof object[key] === 'array') {
      findItemIdAndDateRecursively(id, object[key]);
    }
  })
}

array.forEach(item => {
  findItemIdAndDateRecursively(item.id, item);
})
```

where isUTCString is supposed to find if a string is a date string. You might have to write that utility function depending on the type of data you get.

Answer (score -1):

You could wirte a function that receives the object end returns you the fooDate each time.
This function could do something like breadth-first-search to find this key in the object.

When you have this function you can iterate over the array ob objects and save the latest one you found.